# Flutter: TextFormField Validator breaks the style of field

Tags: flutter

1. I have this TextFormField and i am working on implementing a LogIn/Registration screen. The problem is that when the Validator pops the error onto the screen the borders of the TextFormField change from rounded edges to square shaped. What can i do to just print out the error? I was thinking about printing everything above or below the entire form, but what about a way to do it with the Valdiator property?
   Or is there a more effective way to do it?
2. It also seems that the ListView in which the TextFormField resides gets destroyed in the process making it very annoying to type after the validator gets printed out on the screen.

[beforeValidator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKCue.png)
[afterValidator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTY6o.png)

Just the TextFormField:

```
TextFormField(
                  validator: (String str) =>
                      str.isEmpty ? 'Enter a username' : null,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'theChadMaster76',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                    ),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35.0),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      //focusBorder changes or not when user first clicks on the field
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35.0),
                    ),
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons
                        .account_circle), //make the icon also change its color
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom,
                  onChanged: (String str) {
                    setState(() {
                      userName = str;
                    });
                  },
                ),
```

Entire file:

```
class RegistrationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'registration_screen';
  @override
  _RegistrationScreenState createState() => _RegistrationScreenState();
}

class _RegistrationScreenState extends State<RegistrationScreen> {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool loading = false;
  String error = '';

  String userName = "";
  String email = "";
  String password = "";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return loading ? Loading() : Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBarModel(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
        child: Center(
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50.0),
                  child: Center(child: Text('add logo')),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, bottom: 10.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Username:',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      //fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  validator: (String str) =>
                      str.isEmpty ? 'Enter a username' : null,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'theChadMaster76',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                    ),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35.0),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(

                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35.0),
                    ),
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons
                        .account_circle), //make the icon also change its color
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom,
                  onChanged: (String str) {
                    setState(() {
                      userName = str;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, bottom: 10.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Email:',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      //fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  validator: (String str) =>
                      str.isEmpty ? 'Enter an email' : null,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'bobbyBob@gmail.com',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                    ),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35.0),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(

                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35.0),
                    ),
                    prefixIcon:
                        Icon(Icons.mail),
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom,
                  onChanged: (String str) {
                    setState(() {
                      email = str;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, bottom: 10.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Password:',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      //fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  validator: (String str) =>
                      str.length < 6 ? 'Enter an password 6+ char' : null,
                  obscureText: true,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'secretPassword123!',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                    ),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35.0),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(

                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35.0),
                    ),
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.memory),
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom,
                  onChanged: (String str) {
                    setState(() {
                      password = str;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 50.0,
                ),
                Center(
                  child: FlatButton(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.green.shade400),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.green.shade400,
                    textColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 120.0, vertical: 10.0),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'SUBMIT',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                          letterSpacing: 4.0,
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                        setState(() {
                          loading = true;
                        });
                        dynamic result = await _auth.registerWithEmailPassUser(
                            email, password);
                        if (result == null) {
                          setState(() {
                            loading = false;
                            error = "please supply a valid email";
                          });
                        }
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to override the errorBoder style as well, like the way you did for focusedBorder,enabledBorder. below is the code snippet.

```
errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(

                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35.0),
                    )
```

and your final TextFormFiled should look like

```
TextFormField(
                  validator: (String str) =>
                      str.isEmpty ? 'Enter a username' : null,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'theChadMaster76',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                    ),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35.0),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(

                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35.0),
                    ),
                    errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(

                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35.0),
                    ),
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons
                        .account_circle), //make the icon also change its color
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom,
                  onChanged: (String str) {
                    setState(() {
                      userName = str;
                    });
                  },
                )
```

Comment: you can check the same here https://dartpad.dev/1dc24e6c5a38f6d0a914b3620ea0a20b

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also had to add the focusedErrorBorder and now i see why.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the errorBorder & focusedErrorBorder as well:

```
errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
   borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35.0),
),
focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
   borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35.0),
),
```

Refer [InputDecoration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html) for all the available options.